# 3D Analogue of a Catenary

Tags: geometry, surfaces

When a cable is supported at its ends and droops due to its own weight, the resulting curve is called a [catenary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary).

However, is there a three-dimensional analogue of this shape?

For example, let's say I take the unit square $([0,0,0], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [1,1,0])$, support it at these points, and fill it with a uniform material. It will droop due to its own weight. I have a few questions about the resulting surface:

- Do the edges turn into local catenaries?
- Is there a parametric function that describes this shape?
- Is there a name for this shape?

Any information would be much appreciated!

Comment: [Similar MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69817/surface-equivalent-of-catenary-curve)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly: A flexible (but un-stretchable) wire or thread can bend isometrically into a catenary.

By contrast, two-dimensional materials have internal rigidity coming from [intrinsic curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature#Theorema_egregium). Consequently, an ideal flexible (but un-stretchable) sheet (think of paper or a wire screen) suspended at its corners can only bend upward at the corners with four-fold symmetry.